# How to start a GUI app from the command line in the background?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm using `start cmd.exe /c` to start new command line processes in the background. But when I execute GUI apps this way, it creates an unnecessary command line window.

Comment: "creates an unnecessary".... unnecessary what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the program you want to start needs to be quoted since it contains spaces or shell metacharacters in its path, then you need to supply an empty quoted argument to `start`:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\SomeProgram\Some program.exe"
```

That's because `start` interprets the first quoted argument as the title for a new console window, running `cmd`.

Answer (score 5):

Just say `start myprogram.exe`. It'll return immediately and it won't start an unnecessary instance of the shell.

Comment: Your solution works for `Notepad.exe`. But it doesn't work for the Bitcoin client.